# How do I sort the output of find?

Tags: bash, sorting, find

In below snippet, I merge a number of files with newlines inbetween. However the order of the files doesn't represent my directory structure.

Calling `sort` as shown below doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?

```
find ./lib/app -type f | sort | \
xargs awk 'ENDFILE {print ""} {print}' > myFile
```

Current file order:

```
./lib/app/b/file
./lib/app/config.json
./lib/app/d/file
```

The file order I need:

```
./lib/app/config.json
./lib/app/b/file
./lib/app/d/file
```

Comment: please define better. note that your 2 line sample could be sorted by subdirs. As you've rejected that solution, then you want to sort by filename? (i.e. config.json, template.tpl)? Good luck.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer. I updated my post

Comment: Finally, what needs to be sorted ??? the last part after the ending / ?

Comment: Something like `ls -t` but with directories sorted alphabetically

Comment: Unless you're careless enough to use a sea-shell derivative (`tcsh` etc), the backslash at the end of the line is unnecessary.  Not actually harmful, just unnecessary.

Comment: I put it there for clarification, really :)

Comment: Would it be fair to deduce that the file `./lib/app/b/a/file` should appear after `./lib/app/b/file` but before `./lib/app/d/file` (because it is in a sub-directory of `./lib/app/b`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want the files in a sub-directory listed before any files in a sub-sub-directory.  That's not a standard sort at all.  I think that the algorithm should be, conceptually:

1. If the longest common initial sub-path between two filenames is `X`, then the names are `X/A` and `X/B`.
2. If both `A` and `B` contain one or more slashes, do a straight string comparison (of `A` and `B`).
3. Else if neither `A` nor `B` contains a slash, do a straight string comparison (of `A` and `B`).
4. Else if `A` contains a slash and `B` does not, sort `B` before `A`.
5. Else (`B` contains a slash and `A` does not, so) sort `A` before `B`.

In the sample data:

- F1 = `./lib/app/b/file`
- F2 = `./lib/app/config.json`
- F3 = `./lib/app/d/file`
- F4 = `./lib/app/b/a/file`
- F5 = `./lib/app/b/other`

Comparing:

```
Names      X             A              B              Rule   Result
F1, F2    ./lib/app/     b/file         config.json    4      F2 < F1
F1, F3    ./lib/app/     b/file         d/file         2      F1 < F3
F1, F4    ./lib/app/b/   file           a/file         5      F1 < F4
F1, F5    ./lib/app/b    file           other          3      F1 < F5
F2, F3    ./lib/app/     config.json    d/file         5      F2 < F3
F2, F4    ./lib/app/     config.json    b/a/file       5      F2 < F4
F2, F5    ./lib/app/     config.json    b/other        5      F2 < F5
F3, F4    ./lib/app/     d/file         b/a/file       2      F4 < F3
F3, F5    ./lib/app/     d/file         b/other        2      F5 < F3
F4, F5    ./lib/app/b    a/file         other          3      F5 < F3
```

Coding that in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @files;
while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    push @files, $_;
}

sub pathsorter
{
    my(@abits) = split /\//, $a;
    my(@bbits) = split /\//, $b;


    my $na = scalar(@abits);
    my $nb = scalar(@bbits);
    my $nbits = (($na < $nb) ? $na : $nb) - 1;
    my $i;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $nbits; $i++)
    {
        last if ($abits[$i] ne $bbits[$i]);
    }

    # abits[0..$i] == bbits[0..$i] == X
    return $a cmp $b if ($i < $nbits);
    return $a cmp $b if ($na == $nb && $i == $nbits);
    return -1 if ($na < $nb);
    return +1 if ($na > $nb);
    return 0;
}

print "$_\n" foreach (sort pathsorter @files);
```

Input:

```
./lib/app/b/file
./lib/app/config.json
./lib/base/basename
./lib/app/d/file
./lib/app/b/a/file
./lib/app/b/other
./lib/app/animosity
./lib/base/basename
```

Output:

```
./lib/app/animosity
./lib/app/config.json
./lib/app/b/file
./lib/app/b/other
./lib/app/b/a/file
./lib/app/d/file
./lib/base/basename
./lib/base/basename
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find ./lib/app -type f | sort | tee myFile
```

IMHO, no need [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) there.

Comment: Didn't know about the `tee` command, but it still doesn't sort properly

Comment: You're saying that `find ./lib/app -type f | sort` does not display in sorted order?  That's pretty much impossible.  What does it show?

Comment: Something like this: `./lib/js/app/templates/test.tpl ./lib/js/app/app.coffee ./lib/js/app/views/header.coffee`, ignoring the order of my directory structure

Comment: @Industrial What locale variables do you have set? Does using `find ... | LC_ALL=C sort` sort the way you want? Are there some hidden non-printable characters that snuck into directory/file names somehow?

Comment: Nope. No strange filenames and `LC_ALL=` doesn't make a change

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I could do this to get files first from topmost directory and then alphabetically by subfolders:

```
find ./subfolder ./subfolder/*/ -maxdepth 1 -type f
```

It probably brake if the directory structure changes, but If anyone has a better idea, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need pathnames with fewer slashes sorted first, then:

```
find ... |
perl -e 'print sort {(($a =~ tr{/}{/}) <=> ($b =~ tr{/}{/})) or ($a cmp $b)} <>'
```